# better way of creating jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use the following way two ways to create a plugin. Now I need to know which is better and preferred way.

1st way

```
;(function ($) {
    var Movies = {
        init: function (options, el) {
            this.el = el;
            this.$el = $(el);
            this.url = 'http://example.com/movies.json';

            this.search = (typeof options === 'string') ? options : options.search;
            this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.queryMovies.options, options);

            this.refresh();
        },

        refresh: function () {
            var self = this;
            this.fetch().done(function (results) {
                console.log(results.movies);
            });
        },

        fetch: function () {
            return $.ajax({
                url: this.url,
                data: {
                    q: this.search,
                    apikey: 'thisiskey'
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp'
            });
        }
    };

    $.fn.queryMovies = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var movies = Object.create(Movies);
            movies.init(options, this);
        });
    };

    $.fn.queryMovies.options = {

    };
})(jQuery);
```

2nd way

```
;(function ($) {
    var Movies = function (options, el) {
        this.el = el;
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.url = 'http://example.com/movies.json';

        this.search = (typeof options === 'string') ? options : options.search;
        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.queryMovies.options, options);

        this.refresh();
    };

    Movies.prototype = function () {

        var refresh = function () {
            var self = this;
            fetch(this).done(function (results) {
                console.log(results.movies);
            });
        },

        fetch = function (self) {
            return $.ajax({
                url: self.url,
                data: {
                    q: self.search,
                    apikey: 'thisiskey'
                },
                dataType: 'jsonp'
            });
        };

        return {
            refresh: refresh
        };
    }();

    $.fn.queryMovies = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            new Movies(options, this);
        });
    };

    $.fn.queryMovies.options = {

    };
})(jQuery);
```

The second way has prototypal inheritance. I know that this way is better for memory management. Second, it has a way of having public and private member functions e.g. in above code `refresh` method is public because it has alias inside return object literal whereas `fetch` is private member function.

About the first one, I really don't know whether that is better than the second one. It would be great to know so that from now on I will follow that method.

Answer (score 0):

> The second way has prototypal inheritance. I know that this way is better for memory management.

The first one has as well: `var movies = Object.create(Movies);`. There's not as much difference as you think.

> [The second one] has a way of having public and private member functions e.g. in above code refresh method is public because it has alias inside return object literal whereas fetch is private member function.

`fetch` is not really a member function here (as you see, it doesn't use `this` but does take an `self` instance parameter), it's just a local function. As such, you don't even need the [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to make it local for prototype functions, it would've been easier to just declare a `function fetch` at the same scope as `Movies`:

```
;(function ($) {

    function fetch (self) {
        return $.ajax({
            url: self.url,
            data: {
                q: self.search,
                apikey: 'thisiskey'
            },
            dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }

    function Movies (options, el) {
        this.el = el;
        this.$el = $(el);
        this.url = 'http://example.com/movies.json';

        this.search = (typeof options === 'string') ? options : options.search;
        this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.queryMovies.options, options);

        this.refresh();
    }

    Movies.prototype.refresh = function () {
        var self = this;
        fetch(this).done(function (results) {
            console.log(results.movies);
        });
    };

    $.fn.queryMovies = function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            new Movies(options, this);
        });
    };

    $.fn.queryMovies.options = {

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Notice that you could've used such local-scoped helper functions with the first pattern as well. I would not use the first pattern as constructor functions are easier to grasp and more concise / better to use than manually `Object.create`ing instances and calling `init` methods on them - that's just what [`new`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) was made for.